# How to show the previous version of a static website hosted in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have currently Version 1 and 2 of my static website uploaded into an S3 bucket which has versioning enabled. By default its Version 2 of the website that gets displayed when visitors visit the S3 url. Is there a way to programatically or thru the console set this to display version 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access specific versions of a file in S3 by adding a version to your request, like `http://example.cloudfront.net/image.png?verisonId=[id]`.

You’ll also need to set a bucket policy that allows your CloudFront distribution access to the versioned objects:

```
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Id": "CloudFrontAccessToVersionedObjects",
 "Statement": [{
      "Action": ["s3:GetObject", "s3:GetObjectVersion" ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal":{"CanonicalUser":"<CLOUDFRONT CANONICAL ID>"},
      "Resource": "<BUCKET>",
      "Sid": "CloudFrontAccess"
 }]}
```

After applying the bucket policy you’ll need to invalidate the cache.

As a side note, assuming you always want to use a specific version, a quick way to implement this without having to make any changes to your existing code would be to use a Viewer Request Lambda@Edge to rewrite the request, before it’s passed to your S3 Origin, to append the `versionId=[id]` to all requests to the S3 origin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So there is no inbuilt S3 specific way to look at two different versions of a file and choose one as the current version without adding the version id to the url or via the lambda approach?